# Como fazer leitura, busca e alteração em arquivo por bytes?

Tags: c#, byte

Alguém sabe como faço pra achar mais bytes depois que encontrei a sequência de bytes da minha variável?

por exemplo:
no arquivo vai estar assim: 6261725610

eu vou procurar esse:

```
byte[] findBytes = { 0x62, 0x61, 0x72 };
```

e queria retornar este:

```
byte[] resultado = { 0x62, 0x61, 0x72, 0x56, 0x10 };
```

Aproveitando, como faço para subtrair o último byte?

por exemplo esse:

```
byte[] findBytes = { 0x62, 0x61, 0x72, 0x56, 0x10 };
```

vira esse:

```
byte[] findBytes = { 0x62, 0x61, 0x72, 0x56, 0x8 };
```

Comment: É java isso Pedro?

Comment: desculpe eu esqueci de especificar...estou fazendo em C#

Comment: Este link talvez ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224043/c-sharp-find-offset-of-byte-pattern-check-specific-byte-change-byte-export-pa

Answer (score 3):

Experimenta usar esta biblioteca que eu desenvolvi - [Sequences](https://github.com/dcastro/Sequences) -, torna a manipulação de coleções muito mais fácil. Tem uma API idêntica às coleções de Scala.

```
var bytes = new byte[] {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x62, 0x61, 0x72, 0x56, 0x10}.AsSequence();
var find = new byte[] {0x62, 0x61, 0x72};


var index = bytes.IndexOfSlice(find);
var remaining = bytes.Skip(index);     //retorna 0x62, 0x61, 0x72, 0x56, 0x10
```

(Adicionei uns bytes no inicio do array para demonstrar melhor a pesquisa pela sub-sequência).

- `AsSequence` converte o `byte[]` numa `ISequence<byte>`
- `IndexOfSlice` faz uma pesquisa eficiente pela sub-sequência usando o algoritmo [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)
- `Skip` avanca os elementos que aparecem antes da sub-sequência e retorna os restantes.

Para substituir o último elemento:

```
var replaced = remaining.Init.Append(0x8);   // retorna 0x62, 0x61, 0x72, 0x56, 0x8
```

- `Init` retorna a sequência sem o último elemento
- `Append` junta um elemento ao fim da sequência.

Links

- Nuget: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Sequences
- API: http://diogocastro.com/Sequences/

Comment: Muito legal essa biblioteca! Desculpe sou iniciante e tenho outra dúvida.
 
Eu preciso ler os bytes e pegar um tamanho de bytes variavel, por exemplo:
 
Leio: `var bytes = new byte[] {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x62, 0x61, 0x72, 0x56, 0x10}.AsSequence();`

procura: `var find = new byte[] {0x02};`

quando ele achar 0x02 ele deve ler o proximo byte (0x03) e assumir que ele deve ler mais 3 bytes(poderia ser 0x62 ou outro qualquer), ou seja 
a partir do index que ele achar, ele vai ler mais um tamanho que o próximo byte indicou.

 sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: @PedroHenrique Nao sei se percebi bem o problema... Queres encontrar uma sequência, ler o byte que vem depois da sequência, converter esse byte para um inteiro `n`, e ler os próximos `n` bytes?

Comment: Exatamente :D é para uma aplicação especifica

Comment: @PedroHenrique Experimenta isto: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OysZeF